# Refactoring 2 similar if statements

Tags: php, refactoring

Would you write this code any differently? I don't mind tertiary operator by the way so any ideas that include it are also welcome

```
if ($stopYear < $startYear) {
   for ($i = $startYear; $i >= $stopYear; $i--) {
     $yearMultiOptions[$i] = $i;
   }
} else {
   for ($i = $startYear; $i <= $stopYear; $i++) {
     $yearMultiOptions[$i] = $i;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$step = ($stopYear < $startYear) ? -1 : 1;
for ($i = $startYear; $i != $stopYear; $i += step) {
    $yearMultiOptions[$i] = $i;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$min = min($startYear, $stopYear);
$max = max($startYear, $stopYear);

for ($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++) {
    $yearMultiOptions[$i] = $i;
}
```

I don't know php, so `min` and `max` might have different syntax, but you get the idea.

Comment: Your answer is correct. [`min()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) and [`max()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) have syntax exactly what you have used.